# Operator Overloading on operator + for vectors. Why does the output change depending on the order of addition?

Tags: c++, vector

This is my first post here so sorry for any inconveniences.

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

class OverloadTest : public std::vector<int> {
    public:
        using std::vector<int>::vector;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream &COUT,OverloadTest const &u){
    for(int i=0;i<u.size();i++){
        COUT << u[i] << endl;
    }
    return COUT;
}
OverloadTest& operator+(OverloadTest &u,OverloadTest &v){
    
    std::cout<<"u\n"<<u<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"v\n"<<v<<std::endl;
    for(int i = 0;i<u.size();i++){
        v[i] = u[i] + v[i];
    }
    
    return v;
}
int main(){
    OverloadTest vector1 = {1,1,1};
    OverloadTest vector2 = {3,2,1};
    std::cout<<vector1 + vector2 + vector1<<std::endl;
    
}
```

This works perfectly fine for vector1 + vector2 + vector1.
However if I change
v[i] = u[i] + v[i] to u[i] = u[i] + v[i]

and return u the behaviour of the program becomes wrong.

The output on the console after the change becomes
u
1
1
1

v
3
2
1

u
4
3
2

v
4
3
2

Somehow in the first run which is vector1 + vector2 everything is fine but in the second run u and v are set to (vector1 + vector2) instead of u being set to (vector1 + vector2) and v to vector 1. Switching u and v in the for loop somehow fixes it but I don't understand why and need some clarity.
I appreciate any help coming from you guys.
Best regards

Comment: `operator+` should return a new instance not a reference to one of the operands. What you implemented is `+=` (but also not quite right because `a+=b` should modify `a` not `b`)

Comment: signature of `+` as free function is `T operator+(const T&,const T&)`

Comment: Note the bug you noticed would be present even with `v[i] = u[i] + v[i]`, it'd just be present in `vector1 + vector2 + vector2` instead. You _could_ opt to take a non-reference value of `u`, which then would make a copy of the vector for your `operator+`, which you can return directly or even just `return lhs += rhs;` (by implementing `+=` in a manner similar to what you have here). Any reference value you're taking for this arithmetic operands shoud likely be `const`, since you don't want to change the current values, but produce new ones.